# insert content after jquery redirect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like redirect to a new page and insert content into that page when the new page is loaded all from rails js.erb file.

Here is the success.js.erb file:

```
window.location = "<%=escape_javascript(board_path(@board)) %>";
$(function () {
$('#BtnBoxGreeting').after($("<%= escape_javascript(image_tag 'blankslate-1.png', :width => '429', :height => '103', :alt => 'Blankslate 1', :id => 'blankslate-1' )%>"));
});
```

This does not work as I need some kind of callback function that tells me when the redirected page has loaded.

Anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will never work. The code after setting `window.location` will never run. You need to re-work your code so that the appropriate jQuery is included on the new page and is run at the appropriate time (perhaps `$(document).ready()`).

If you are trying to update just a portion of the page, check out [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax). Using that function you could request new HTML and update existing content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to basically write code on the redirected page load event using $(document).ready(). It is not at all possible what you want.